# Keycode issues - works almost with ctrlKey

Tags: javascript, html, events, keycode

I've a written a JavaScript that opens a specific page in the "content" div when I click on a link.

HTML:

```
<li><a href='#' onclick="load_shift_test()">Soft Drinks</a></li>
```

JS:

```
function load_shift_test(){
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/php" data="mineralwater.php" ></object>';
```

This works, however, I need it to choose between 2 pages if a certain key is pressed when clicking on the link so I rewrote the script this way:

```
function load_shift_test(){
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/php" data="mineralwater.php" ></object>';
 if (event.ctrlKey) 
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/php" data="mineralwateredit.php"></object>';

}
```

This also works but it will also opens a new tab in Chrome and I really don`t like it.

I would ideally like the page to open if the key "e" (without ctrl) is pressed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is Chrome is overriding Ctrl+click as a new window shortcut before triggering any JS event. If you want "e" to be a modifier key, create a jQuery event that tracks the state of the key position.

```
window.keyDown = false; //Start with key down is false
$(document).keyup(function(event) { //On key up switch to false
  window.keyDown = (event.keyCode == 69) ? false : window.keyDown; 
} ).keydown(function(event) { //On key down switch to true
  window.keyDown = (event.keyCode == 69) ? true : window.keyDown; 
} );
```

Then you can take action in `load_shift_test()` by checking the global variable `window.keyDown`.

Comment: Nailed it ! Thank so much !!

Answer (score 0):

When a user do `ctrl + click` on any hyperlink, the normal browser behavior is to open this hyperlink  in new tab. This behavior cannot be stopped by JavaScript code.

However if you want to stop opening a new tab you need to remove the `href` attribute from the anchor link or just use another HTML element (ex. div, span).

Here is a [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kxvm24mn/).